# How do I draw a Drop Shadow at any Location on a Form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing, gdi+

Using GDI+, how do I draw a Border Shadow or a Drop Shadow at specified coordinates? I'm not trying to attach the shadow to anything, I just need to draw a shadow from x40,0px to x140px,0px. I've not been able to find any information about this and I'm beginning to think it isn't possible.

My intention is to draw a shadow at certain location at bottom of control but I don't want it to be the entire width of the control, which is why I've asked specifically about only drawing at specified locations.

Comment: I'm interested to see why you'd want a drop shadow seemingly 'randomly' on your winform? What is the effect you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Complete control over where it is drawn. The _only_ solutions I've been able to find draw the shadow from the bottom left all the way to the bottom right of the control. I need more control over where the shadow begins and where it ends. Existing solutions "which solve a different problem" do not allow for any further control over the start and end points of the shadow.

Comment: How do you draw a shadow now and what is wrong with it? Shadow is not something to be *controlled*. Do you want animate shadow or what? In graphics word dropping shadow is expensive. So most of solutions are optimized for real-time operation (fake shadows). In physical word you don't control shadow directly either, you control objects, lights, distances, etc. and shadow is produces based on those. Its a bit confusing what your definition of shadow means: *a shadow from x40,0px to x140px,0px*. Who drops it? Can you create a sketch or screenshot to describe the problem visually?

Comment: Create an png image of the shadow and then draw a portion of this image where you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that could get you started.

The `drawShadow` method draws a shadow of given color and depth along a `GraphicsPath`.

The use of `GraphicsPath` allows you to draw shadows of more complex shapes than mere `Rectangles`.

The shadow is drawn with a vector of colors that gradually goes from the shadow to the background color and is moving to the right and down. (You can change the direction by changing the shadow vector. Values greater 1 will need an larger Pen width! (*) )

To demonstrate the routine I have added a `getRectPath` function that creates a `GraphicsPath` from a `Rectangle` and a Button click that calls the drawing routine.

Of course in production code you must attach it to the `Paint` event instead!

```
void drawShadow(Graphics G, Color c, GraphicsPath GP, int d)
{
    Color[] colors = getColorVector(c, this.BackColor, d).ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        G.TranslateTransform(1f, 0.75f);                // <== shadow vector!
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(colors[i], 1.75f  ) )  // <== pen width (*)
            G.DrawPath(pen, GP);
    }
    G.ResetTransform();
}


List<Color> getColorVector(Color fc, Color bc, int depth)
{
    List<Color> cv = new List<Color>();
    float dRed = 1f * (bc.R - fc.R) / depth;
    float dGreen = 1f * (bc.G - fc.G) / depth;
    float dBlue = 1f * (bc.B - fc.B) / depth;
    for (int d = 1; d <= depth; d++)
         cv.Add(Color.FromArgb(255,   (int) (fc.R + dRed * d),
           (int) (fc.G + dGreen * d), (int) (fc.B + dBlue * d) ));
    return cv;
}

GraphicsPath getRectPath(Rectangle R)
{
    byte[] fm = new byte[3];
    for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) fm[b] = 1;
    List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
    points.Add(new Point(R.Left, R.Bottom));
    points.Add(new Point(R.Right, R.Bottom));
    points.Add(new Point(R.Right, R.Top));
    return new GraphicsPath(points.ToArray(), fm);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics G = this.CreateGraphics())
      drawShadow(G, Color.Black, getRectPath(new Rectangle(111, 111, 222, 222)), 17);
}
```

**Edit:** I have changed the solution to allow for complex shadows and arbitrary shadow vectors  without the alpha channel's overlapping creating ugly artifacts. This assumes that the background has a uniform color!